# Chrome update affects CSS text-overflow in relation to text-indent

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, chromium

In Chrome, the indented (`text-indent`) version of an item with `text-overflow` no longer behaves the same as it used to.

Previous to the Chrome version `77.0.3865.75`, indented text would still show an ellipsis. [I can see that in the changes they've modified the way text-overflow works in the Chromium project](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/76.0.3809.132..77.0.3865.75?pretty=fuller&n=10000.).

In Firefox, Safari, and Edge, the indentation still works the same as it used to (see Codepens below for testing)

**My questions:**

1. Any ideas about a good way to solve this issue?
2. For my own education, is this a Chromium bug or are the other browsers not following spec?

**Examples:**

Given this HTML:

```
<div>
  <h1>A long title over a character limit</h1>
  <h1 class="indent">A long title over a character limit</h1>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
div {
  width: 25em;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 1em;
}

h1 {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

h1.indent {
  text-indent: 2em;
}
```

We see that in Chromium-based browsers, the `h1.indent` version of the title does not have an ellipsis.

Again in Firefox and other browsers, the `text-overflow` works as expected. In newer Chromium-based browsers it doesn't.
Screenshot:
[image]

Here is a copy of the HTML/CSS in a codepen:
https://codepen.io/camsjams/pen/yLBGBvP

Here is a codepen showing this in an HTML table:
https://codepen.io/camsjams/pen/dybwbWr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by a change in Chrome, and has been fixed in the Chromium development channel.

Here is the bug I had made on the Chromium issues site: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1006395#c5

I will update with proper version number once the release is finalized.

**Update:** In Chrome versions `Version 81.0.4044.92` or newer, this bug is fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Chrome Version 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit) is behaving now in another unexpected way.

Issue:  using text-indent, overflow:hidden (required to use text-overflow:ellipsis) and text-overflow:ellipsis together pushes ellipsis out of visible space based on text-indent value.

Here is some basic CSS and HTML showing the behavior and a screenshot below that.

```html
<style>
 #test1{
  text-indent:1px;
 }
 #test2{
  text-indent:10px;
 }
 .ellipsis{
  border:1px solid #000;
  width:200px;
  margin:50px;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  white-space:nowrap;
 }
</style>

<div id="test1" class="ellipsis">
 Here is some really long text for testing purposes
</div>
<div id="test2" class="ellipsis">
 Here is some really long text for testing purposes
</div>
```

Results in Chrome at above mentioned version:

[image]

Comment: Hi Nick -  In Chrome versions `Version 81.0.4044.92` or newer, the bug you posted is fixed!